# How do I install tesseract-ocr v4.1.1 in a docker image

Tags: docker, ubuntu, dockerfile, tesseract, wsl-2

I'm trying to build a docker image that will run on WSL-2 Ubuntu-20.04 (hosted on Windows 10).
I need to install the version 4.1.1 of tesseract-ocr, which according to https://ubuntu.pkgs.org/20.04/ubuntu-universe-arm64/tesseract-ocr_4.1.1-2build2_arm64.deb.html is 4.1.1-2build2.   This line should work:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install tesseract-ocr -y
```

But it installs V 4.0.0.  So, I tried this line:

```
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install tesseract-ocr=4.1.1-2build2 -y
```

which gives me this error:

> Version '4.1.1-2build2' for 'tesseract-ocr' was not found

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Tried with 20.04 and the latest version of Ubuntu docker image, either found the package. Please update your question with the full Dockerfile if the problem persists.

Comment: I didn't think of that I was using a python base image for my docker.  Thanks, that worked.

Comment: Alternatively, this method (not recommended very slow) also worked: I decided to build the image myself and was successful using these lines in the Dockerfile:

    RUN export PATH=/user/local/bin:$PATH
    RUN apt update && apt install libleptonica-dev automake pkg-config libsdl-pango-dev libicu-dev libcairo2-dev bc ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6  -y
    RUN wget https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/archive/4.1.1.zip && unzip 4.1.1.zip && cd tesseract-4.1.1 && ./autogen.sh && ./configure && make && make install && ldconfig && make training && make training-install && tesseract --version

Comment: @PhilO instead of giving the solution in comments, please add it in answers section. It is helpful.

Answer (score 0):

From @phil-o's comment:

```
RUN export PATH=/user/local/bin:$PATH 

RUN apt-get update && \ 
    apt-get install libleptonica-dev automake make pkg-config libsdl-pango-dev libicu-dev libcairo2-dev bc ffmpeg libsm6 libxext6 -y 

RUN wget github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/archive/4.1.1.zip && \
    unzip 4.1.1.zip && \
    cd tesseract-4.1.1 && \
     ./autogen.sh && \
     ./configure && \
     make && \
     make install && \
     ldconfig && \
     make training && \
     make training-install && \
     tesseract --version
```

this works for me.